# What's the difference between life expectancy of cigarette smoker and general population?

Tags: epidemiology, smoking

Some say that smoking cigarettes will shorten lifespan. By how many years is the lifespan of a typical smoker shortened? What are the common cause(s) of death among smokers? Are there any known statistics for cigarette smoking and life expectancy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference in life expectancy between smokers and non-smokers appears to be at least 10 years on average, in a [survey of American adults between 1997 and 2004](http://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJMsa1211128).

The same paper lists causes of death (higher among smokers than non-smokers, as measured by hazard ratio), although this is not exhaustive: lung cancer, other cancers, ischemic heart disease, stroke, other vascular disease, and respiratory disease have an adjusted hazard ratio of 1.7 or more, with 94% of lung cancer deaths attributable to smoking among female smokers, and 93% to smoking among male smokers.

If you have access, you will probably find Table 2 (hazard ratios) of interest.

Figure 2 shows the survival probability:
[image: Survival probabilities - smokers vs non smokers]

Comment: I have added Figure 2 to the answer (it is free to view and it is clearly fair use anyways)

Comment: @nico: may I ask how you extracted it? I couldn't find a link.

Comment: There is a link to the PDF on the right, copied, saved it on my HD then uploaded it here (or you can just grab a screenshot).

Comment: What is interesting is the multiplicative effect of industrial disease with smoking,  in lectures (regrettably unreferenced slides) we are advised that in the case of asbestosis risk ratio for lung cancer (**not** mesothelioma)  is 7 in a non-smoker but a staggering 93 in smokers with asbestosis.

Comment: Bravo. I am speechless. Do we have the same data for ganja?

Comment: @JimThio: I think that data is a little harder to come by, given the different legal status in different states (I am not aware of research outside the US).  You might find this interesting though: http://www.nap.edu/catalog.php?record_id=6376

Comment: @JimThio while marijuana actually has some protective effects (as demonstrated in mice, don't have the reference at hand), the basic problem in smoking is the act of smoking itself not what it is that you are inhaling. Whether you smoke weed or tobacco, you are still inhaling carbon monoxide and screwing up your haemoglobin and you are still ingesting free radicals and screwing up your DNA. Sorry (and I truly am, I am a heavy smoker of various substances).

Comment: @terdon: seriously doubt you would ever "ingest" (although inhale would be the correct word) free radicals from smoking. They are too short lived and reactive to be actually directly inhaled.

Comment: @nico, [The gas phase of cigarette smoke contains small oxygen- and carbon-centered radicals that are much more reactive than are the tar-phase radicals.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1568603/) and that's just the first random reference I found. Also, although I live in France, English is my native language :). _Ingest_ is quite correct in that context. The Oxford Dictionary Online even uses this phrase as an [example](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ingest) of the word's usage: "_they ingest oxygen from the air_"

Comment: @terdon: I mantain that you inhale smoke, you do not ingest it. *Ingest* is mostly used for food (Oxford English Dictionary, offline edition :P). English aside, I do not doubt that smoke contains radicals, what I am saying is that they are most likely not those that directly affect DNA. They will rather generate cascade reactions creating new radicals, oxidising proteins and so on, especially in such a oxygen-rich milieu as the lungs.

Comment: @nico I only used _ingest_ to avoid a third repetition of _inhale_ so I won't push the point :). As for whether they directly affect DNA or start a cascade, I honestly have no idea. The abstract of the paper I linked to seems to claim that both are true: "Cigarette smoke contains two very different populations of free radicals, one in the tar and one in the gas phase. [...] In addition, we have shown that the principal radical in tar reacts with DNA in vitro, possibly by covalent binding". Anyway, my main point was just that _whatever_ you smoke, the act of smoking is harmful.

Comment: @terdon: agree. I was just nitpicking